# Difference between git push --mirror and git set-url

Tags: git

I'm currently migrating repos from bitbucket to github and encountered two ways of doing this:

1. Clone existing and push to mirror:

- `git clone --mirror {url}`
- `git push --mirror {url}`

2. Just change origin of local repo:

- `git remote set-url origin {url}`

What the difference between this two methods and which should be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not different methods of doing the same thing, they are separate steps of the same process.

To take the simpler one first, `git remote set-url origin {url}` just tells a particular local copy of the repo what remote repo you mean when you say "origin". It doesn't copy any data anywhere, it just configures what future commands like `git fetch origin`, `git push origin`, or `git pull origin` will do.

To actually migrate the repo, you need to copy some actual data, and that means running some variant of `git push`. You could just configure the new URL for `origin` and then `git push origin master`; but now your new repo will only have history accessible from `master`; it won't include any un-merged branches, or any tags. So instead you can add the `--mirror` option, which basically means "push everything you know about" (it also means "overwrite anything the remote end disagrees about", but that doesn't matter if the remote end is empty).

The final piece of the puzzle is that a normal local copy has its own set of branches, normally just the ones you've worked with; that won't include all the branches on the original remote repo, and may well include things you never pushed up, or have already deleted. So you want to start with a copy that exactly matches the remote repo, and to do that you use the `--mirror` option to `git clone`.

So the actual process actually involves all three of the commands you gave:

```sh
# Create a temporary clone for the migration
git clone --mirror {old-url} temp-clone
cd temp-clone
git push --mirror {new-url}
# This is no longer needed
cd ..
rm -rf temp-clone
# Now point your normal working copy at the new remote repo
cd working-copy
git remote set-url origin {new-url}
git fetch origin
```